# Binary file handling in Python

Tags: python, file-handling

I am trying to write & display the id ,name and salary of 3 employees from .dat file using pickle methods in Python but while displaying I am able to see only 1 employee details the rest are not coming. Please suggest as where the problem is in the below code.

```
import pickle

class Emp:
    def __init__(self, id, name, sal):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.sal = sal
    def display(self):
        print('{} {} {}'.format(self.id, self.name, self.sal))
    
n = int(input('How many employees?'))
for i in range(n):
    id = int(input('Enter the id:'))
    name = input('Enter name:')
    sal = float(input('Enter salary: '))
    f = open('emp.dat', 'wb')    
    e = Emp(id, name, sal)
    pickle.dump(e, f)
f = open('emp.dat', 'rb')
print('Employee details: ')
obj = pickle.load(f)
obj.display()
```

Example run:

```
INPUT: 
How many employees?2
Enter the id:12
Enter name:john
Enter salary: 89000
Enter the id:34
Enter name:mark
Enter salary: 83111
obj.display()
OUTPUT:
Employee details: 
12 john 89000.0
```

Comment: Off-topic: look up [the with statement](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/). It avoids having to explicitly close the file every time.

Comment: @Maaz Is there any way to bring the cursor to the next line if i want to use 'wb', i want the cursor to move to the next line at each iteration

Comment: Open the file ***once***, before the loop... You also never close the files

Comment: Just add an "\n" at the end, and you'll start on a new line. But please be careful with using `wb`, as @Tomerikoo rightfully suggested, it "truncates the file upon opening".

Answer (score 2):

You're opening the file using `wb` (`w`rite `b`inary). The `w` mode truncates (empties) the file upon opening, so you're effectively overwriting the records as you go.

Instead use `ab` (`a`ppend `b`inary) (and as @Maaz mentioned, use the `with` statement).

Furthermore, when reading data from the file, you will need to loop for as long as you can to read all of the records. (Happily `pickle` is a concatenation-tolerant format, so you can just read and read.)

```
import pickle


class Emp:
    def __init__(self, id, name, sal):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.sal = sal

    def display(self):
        print("{} {} {}".format(self.id, self.name, self.sal))


n = int(input("How many employees?"))
for i in range(n):
    id = int(input("Enter the id:"))
    name = input("Enter name:")
    sal = float(input("Enter salary: "))
    with open("emp.dat", "ab") as f:
        e = Emp(id, name, sal)
        pickle.dump(e, f)

with open("emp.dat", "rb") as f:
    while True:
        try:
            obj = pickle.load(f)
        except EOFError:  # Nothing to read
            break
        print("Employee details: ")
        obj.display()
```

Alternately (as discussed in comments), if you want to clear the file but write a number of new records, open the file in `w` mode only once, then write into it multiple times.

```
with open("emp.dat", "wb") as f:
    for i in range(n):
        id = int(input("Enter the id:"))
        name = input("Enter name:")
        sal = float(input("Enter salary: "))
        e = Emp(id, name, sal)
        pickle.dump(e, f)
```

Comment: is there any way to bring the cursor to the next line while using 'wb'. I mean during each iteration the cursor should come to the next line while continue using open function

Comment: this is appending after previous i do not want to see any records at each fresh run of the program

Comment: There should be no such thing as "next line" when using binary files.

Comment: See my edit – to clear the file and write new records, open it _once_ using the `wb` mode.

Comment: I have edited your read code in order to display the print statement only once rather than printing each time :      with open("emp.dat", "rb") as f:
    print("Employee details: ")
    while True:
        try:
            obj = pickle.load(f)
            obj.display()
        except EOFError:  # Nothing to read
            break

Comment: Sure, that's a minor detail. If my answer helped you, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pickle

class Emp:
    def __init__(self, id, name, sal):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.sal = sal
    def display(self):
        print('{} {} {}'.format(self.id, self.name, self.sal))

n = int(input('How many employees?'))
emps = []
for i in range(n):
    id = int(input('Enter the id:'))
    name = input('Enter name:')
    sal = float(input('Enter salary: '))
    e = Emp(id, name, sal)
    emps.append(e)
with open('emp.dat', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(emps, f)
with open('emp.dat', 'rb') as f:
    print('Employee details: ')
    objs = pickle.load(f)
    for obj in objs:
        obj.display()
```

Example run:

```
How many employees?2
Enter the id:1
Enter name:a
Enter salary: 10
Enter the id:2
Enter name:b
Enter salary: 20
Employee details: 
1 a 10.0
2 b 20.0
```

Comment: This is not exactly the same thing – it's writing a single list object into the file, not several "free" objects.

Comment: Agree with you @AKX